# Internal error when training a model in AutoML Tables

Tags: google-cloud-ml

[Internal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UjTf.png)
Help I got internal error when training my table, my storage bucket is in us-central1 (Iowa).My dataset contains many empty value, is it the problem?

> Error details
>
> Operation ID: projects/776833785397/us-central1/operations/TBL620410101235394272
>
> Error Message: INTERNAL

Comment: Turns out that I have duplicates columns in my dataset that cause the error.

Comment: Interestingly no error that point out to duplicate column names?

Comment: I think the reason is that I forgot to reformat the data cells to number with same decimal places in the csv file.